# username/passowrd authentication for a basic IIS site

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I am trying to set up some basic authentication so that only people who have a username and password can access the IIS7 site. Currently all the people on my school network can access the site but i want to create an authentication system so that only few people can access the site.

I googled around and found about the basic authentication
[image]

I had enabled the authentication as shown below

[image]

I had also went to the Turn Windows Features on and Off and found enbaled the basic authentication

[image]

I am not sure where I can specify the usernames and passwords. if i go to localhost, I am still getting the same page without out any dialog box asking me to provide my credentials.  In case it matters, I am using windows 7.

Comment: You still have anonymous authentication enabled. You'll need to disable that.

Comment: Using Basic authentication may not be good idea if you are using http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to disable anonymous authentication, then you can setup your user to have access to it:

For Windows 7/8 machines:
Right click on Computer and choose "Manage" (or go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management) and under "Local Users and Groups" you can add a new user. Then, give that user permission to read the directory where the site is hosted.

**Note**: After creating the user, be sure to edit the user and remove all roles. This prevents access of the user to the machine.

For Windows Server machines:
There is that option where you can add users from IIS Manager UI. These users have roles only on IIS, but not for the rest of the system